# Re-wording of tag synonym error

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms, error-message

Currently, if you try to suggest a tag synonym without a score of 5, it says:

[image]

Such as when I tried to suggest a vim synonym. So I checked my score:

[image]

Indeed, the number says `4`, but when you mouse over, you can see that it only counts votes for answers, not questions. Which may not be a problem, except that the mouseover says I have a "score" of 5 on questions as well. This is confusing.

I suggest changing the wording of the orange error to:

> Sorry, creating a tag synonym requires a score of 5 from answers in this tag.

Or something similar. This stipulation should also be listed on the [Privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) page. Currently it is not.

Comment: Is it my browser or there is an error in the pictures?!

Comment: I agree with this having just encountered the same issue - the wording is quite unclear at the moment, and arguably contradictory.